# How do I stop my flexbox containers from overflowing?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a website for my aunt, a mobile therapist. Currently my problem is that I can't stop the images under the treatments section from overlapping. Can someone help me?
I've resized them so that they have a width of 250% and a height of 180%. I didn't expect that when I used flex containers they would overlap like this. Is this normal?

Stack overflow wouldn't let me input all of my code here with too few words so here is a link of my working code on CodePen: https://codepen.io/wmufunde/pen/yPLZgG

```css
 /* ================================= 
      Media Queries
    ==================================== */
    
    @media (min-width: 769px) {
        .main-header,
        .main-nav,
        .row {
            display: flex;
        }
        
        .main-header {
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items:center;
        }
        
       .banner {
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-end;
            flex-direction:row;
            flex: 2;
           justify-content: space-between;
        }
        
        
        .col {
            flex: 1;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            
        }
    
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 1025px) {
        
        .main-header {
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        
        .primary {
            flex: 2;
        }
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Best City Guide</title>
     <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexbox.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     
     <header class="main-header">
      <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Best City Guide</a></h1>
      <ul class="main-nav">
       <li><a href="#">ice cream</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">donuts</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">tea</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">coffee</a></li>
      </ul>
     </header><!--/.main-header-->   
    
     <div class="banner">
     <img class="logo" src="img/white-lilly.png" alt="lilly">
      
      <h1 class="headline">Simply Divine</h1>
      <br>
    <!--  <span class="tagline">Feel Good, Look Good.</span>-->
     </div><!--/.banner-->
     
     
     <div class = "my-row">
         <div class = "massage">
    <!--         <img src ="img/massage1.jpg" alt="massage">-->
         </div>
     </div>
     
     <section class ="treatments">
     <div class="row">  
      <div class="col">
       <img src ="img/manicure.jpg">
      </div><!--/.primary-->
      
      <div class="col">
       <img src ="img/pedicure.jpg">
      </div><!--/.secondary-->
      
      <div class="col">
          <img src = "img/massage2.jpg">
      </div>
          
     </div>
     
     <div class ="row">
         <div class = "col">
             <img src = "img/indian-head-massage.jpg">
         </div>
         
         <div class = "col">
             <img src = "img/wrap-massage.jpg">
         </div>
         
         <div class = "col">
             <img src = "img/facial.jpg">
         </div>
     </div>
     </section>
     
     <section class ="treatments">
     <div class="row">  
      <div class="primary col">
       
      </div><!--/.primary-->
      
      <div class="secondary col">
       
      </div><!--/.secondary-->
      
      <div class="third col"></div>
     </div>
     </section>
     
     
     <footer class="main-footer">
      <span>&copy;2015 Residents of The Best City Ever.</span>
     </footer>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: When asking a question it is better to narrow down your code to minimum, nobody should examine whole bunch of your codes in attempt to figure out what do you asking about

Comment: That's fine. Thank you for the tip. I think the problem is in the flexbox.css file.

Comment: You are supposed to provide a _minimal_ working code snippet reproducing the issue _within_ the question itself, and not as an external link, as when that link dies, so does the value of this question to future users.

Comment: @WadzanaiMufunde Where's the point in giving 250% and 180% for images, set both to 100% or don't even use it.

Comment: @VXp It wasn't rendering properly with anything lower than 100% and since it's perfectly valid CSS I don't see the problem.

Comment: @WadzanaiMufunde So you'r saying there's no problem with your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in a way you're defining image styles. Your current style from example link is:

```
.col img {
    width:250%;
    height:180%; 
}
```

You may think that percent value for `width` and `height` means "that more percents from original image size" but actual meaning of this value [defined into specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Values) is "percent of size of containing block".

To resize image while retaining its aspect ratio you need to control only one axis of its size and let browser to calculate size of opposite axis according to image's actual size. So replacing your style with:

```
.col img {
    width:250%;
    height:auto; 
}
```

will eliminate oversized images and will solve your images overlapping problem. Of course `width: 250%` is also redundant since you don't need to have image size wider then container size. Hence final style is:

```
.col img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Why do the images only work properly the way I want them to when I set width to 100% and height to 100%? If I change one to auto then I get white spaces.

Comment: If you will re-read my answer about meaning of percentage values for size definition - you will see that size is calculated against containing element. If your **actual** question is how to fill container with image - there is completely different approach to use